# Cannot set "ExternalId" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I am trying to convert a .CSV file into a .XML file using PowerShell.

Here is my code:

```
[xml]$xml = "
<Cv>
<Owner>
    <ExternalId></ExternalId>
    <Name></Name>
</Owner>
<Content>
   <Educations>
   </Educations>
</Content>
</Cv>"

$basePath= "C:\Users\test\source\CERTSUMMARY.CSV"
$targetBase = "C:\Users\test\source\target"

$sert = Import-CSV $basePath -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($person in $sert) {
    $xml2 = $xml.Clone()
    $xml2.Cv.Owner.ExternalId = $person.Användarnamn
    $xml2.Cv.Owner.Name = $person.Namn
```

I've looked here for an answer and tried the suggestions that other developers has said. I've tried to put `[string]$person.Användarnamn`, I've tried `$xml2.Cv.Owner.ExternalId.ToString()` and I have also tried to change the values inside the CSV file, but without any result.

The error message is as the topic says:

> "Cannot set "ExternalId" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties."

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an encoding issue there. Your column title contains a special character (`ä`) that isn't defined in ASCII (the encoding `Import-Csv` uses by default), so the property most likely shows up as `Anv?ndarnamn` (you can verify by echoing `$sert[0]`). In that case the imported objects have no property `Användarnamn`. Since PowerShell expands non-existent properties to `$null` the statement

```
$xml2.Cv.Owner.ExternalId = $person.Användarnamn
```

would try to assign `$null` to the XML node, which doesn't work.

Try importing the file with the `Default` encoding:

```
$sert = Import-Csv $basePath -Delimiter ';' -Encoding Default
```

If that doesn't help you probably need to save the CSV in a format that does support special characters (e.g. UTF8).

Comment: Hello Ansgar,

 Iv'e tried all of your suggestions above and the problem remains. 
But thank you for the response :)

regards,

Comment: For further help please update your question with sample input.

Comment: Iv'e updated with the .CSV file and some data in that column and code sample from the .PS1 file.

I changed "Användarnamn" to "Username" but still get the same error message. Would you like to post a picture of the error in PS aswell?

Comment: Please show the actual CSV data, not a screenshot after importing it in Excel. CSV is just structured plain text, so you can open the file in any editor.

Comment: Linked a picture of it now @Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: Solved. The problem was that I didn't change the "ä" letters in the Script to "a" letters and so on :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference your null xml elements with .InnerText

```
foreach ($person in $sert) {
$xml2 = $xml.Clone()
$xml2.Cv.Owner.ExternalId.InnerText = $person.Användarnamn
$xml2.Cv.Owner.Name.InnerText = $person.Namn
```